# Removing object from IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am returning a list of IEnumerable from one method. How do i remove an element from it?

i want to do something like :-

objIEnumerable.remove(objCustomer)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how does this question relate to "NotFound"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a readonly, forward-only access collection. You cannot remove elements. You might need to cast it to the underlying type and see if it supports this operation.